# How to start splash screen in landscape mode?

Tags: android, landscape, splash-screen

I am trying to launch my application in Landscape. In my application, I am using a splash Screen Image (480 X 320). I've looked online but found no answers to my problem, my Splash image keeps appearing in Portrait mode.

Can Anyone suggest how to implement the Splash Screen in Landscape mode?
Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Set the activity to landscape in your manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the activity where you have the 'splash screen':

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

By the way, this seems a very bad practice. Also, unless you have an app like a game where you will be loading a lot of data when starting up the app, splash screens should be avoided as much as posible. You want the user to get the app up and running as soon as posible.

Comment: Thanks man and thanks for the info. The only thing is I'm getting an error here (ActivityInfo) it says ActivityInfo cannot be resolved to a variable??